# Mapping <C-j> to something in Vim

Tags: vim

I have mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> to move to the buffer below. However it was hard mapped
to something else so I had to write the first row below to make it mappable at
all.

The script below works perfectly, except when I write .sh files. I have
bash-support plugin installed.

```
let g:C_Ctrl_j = 'off'
map <C-j> <C-w>j
```

EDIT: I have just found out that the problem is in bash-support. Bash-support
maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> to jump insert (or something like that) which moves cursor at a
predefined point and goes to insert mode. I guess changing that in bash-support
script will do the job though I don't like messing with those files.

EDIT2: let g:C_Ctrl_j = 'off' actually turns the csupport plugin jump insert feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the document of bash-support.vim](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/bashsupport.html#bashsupport-Ctrl-j):

> The original meaning of Ctrl-j is 'move [n] lines downward' (see |CTRL-j|).
>   If you are accustomed to use the default and don't like these jump targets you
>   can switch them off.  Put the following line in the file '.vimrc' :
>
> let g:BASH_Ctrl_j   = 'off'

So that you have to put `let g:BASH_Ctrl_j = 'off'` into your vimrc.

Additionally, use `nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j` instead of `map <C-j> <C-w>j` in your vimrc.
The latter defines key mappings in Normal, Visual and Operator-pending modes.
The key mappings are also recursively expanded.
It might cause troubles when you define more key mappings.

Comment: The `nnoremap` instead of `map` fixed the problem for me! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> (0x0A) is a special character, [Line Feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

There's a good chance that this key-press is not is not arriving at Vim as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> (0x0A).

In Vim in a Terminal.app window on my Mac, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> displays `^@`, (0x00 or NULL). Whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>  display `^G` and `^K`, respectively.

I'd suggest using another mapping (or just training yourself to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd>).

Comment: let g:C_Ctrl_j = 'off' Does removes the hard mapping of Ctrl-j to Line Feed.

Comment: Really? Where's that documented? I've tried on two computers and it makes no difference.

Comment: http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/csupport.html#csupport-Ctrl-j This is part of the csupport documentation explains the role of Ctrl-j in csupport plugin. I have read about this remapping somewhere a few months ago and I have no idea where it was.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but for a different reason. VIM-LaTeX uses [imaps.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/imaps.vim) plugin, which also [remaps some keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62134/how-to-disable-all-vim-latex-mappings), including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>. What worked for me is to set an `autocmd` in my `.vimrc`:

```
augroup vimrc
    au!
    au VimEnter * unmap <C-j>
    au VimEnter * noremap <C-j> <C-w>j
augroup END
```

The `VimEnter` trigger makes sure that the remap will executed after vim starts up, and the plug-ins are loaded (if I understand it correctly), so it overwrites the imaps.vim plug-in's maps. The unmap isn't necessary, but it can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Try non recursive mappings,

```
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
```

ought to do it.